# In Rasa SDK, how can I retrieve logs from the action server running locally?

Tags: logging, rasa-core, rasa

I have several custom actions running on my action server. I would like to get custom log messages from within these custom actions using the logging module. However, I cannot find the logs I am generating.

In my action files, I use:

```
import logging
logger = logging.Logger(__name__)

# in any function
logger.debug("Some log message")
```

If I run my action server locally with: rasa run actions --actions actions --debug, these log messages do not appear although the function is executed. The only logs I get are of the form:

```
2019-08-06 12:00:14 DEBUG    rasa.cli.utils  - 'actions.py' not found. Using default location 'actions' instead.
2019-08-06 12:00:14 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server...
2019-08-06 12:00:20 INFO     rasa_sdk.executor  - Registered function for 'action_display_selector'.
2019-08-06 12:00:20 INFO     rasa_sdk.executor  - Registered function for 'action_explain'.
2019-08-06 12:00:20 INFO     rasa_sdk.executor  - Registered function for 'action_show_pictures'.
2019-08-06 12:00:20 INFO     rasa_sdk.executor  - Registered function for 'form_contact'.
2019-08-06 12:00:20 INFO     rasa_sdk.executor  - Registered function for 'form_preferences'.
2019-08-06 12:00:20 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Action endpoint is up and running. on ('0.0.0.0', 5055)
2019-08-06 12:01:20 DEBUG    rasa_sdk.executor  - Received request to run 'action_display_selector'
2019-08-06 12:01:20 DEBUG    rasa_sdk.executor  - Finished running 'action_display_selector'
127.0.0.1 - - [2019-08-06 12:01:20] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 208 0.515258
```

Where and how I can retrieve my custom log messages?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was an easy fix actually. I needed to use `logging.getLogger(__name__)` instead of `logging.Logger(__name__)`

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# in any function
logger.debug("Some log message")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the solution proposed here with no luck. However, another thread in the Rasa forum (found here: ["Debugging or Logging Custom Component"](https://forum.rasa.com/t/debugging-or-logging-custom-component/2781/4)) had a slightly different suggestion to set a basic config calling `logging.getLogger(__name__)` shown below:

```
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
```

This worked for me. If relevant, I'm using rasa-sdk 2.2.0 inside a docker container. Remember to use the `--debug` or `-vv` flag when starting your action server endpoint to ensure that you actually get the debug messages, since the default mode seems to be `--verbose` or `-v`, which will only show info logs.